# Focus on code after CTRL+F (Find) in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio

Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio 2022, after searching a term with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, to set back focus to the code WITHOUT loosing the search? I do this to keep editing while the found tokens are highlighted.
You can of course click on the code with the mouse but I'd like to be able to do this with the keyboard.

I found a similar question here: [Visual Studio: set focus to text editor](https://superuser.com/questions/1365162/visual-studio-set-focus-to-text-editor) but none of the proposed answers worked for me. The `Window.ActivateDocumentWindow` just wont do anything.

In Visual Studio 2019 I was just using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> two time (the first time would switch to another tab) but now it will automatically focus the search box again!

Comment: `ESC` then use `F3` to jump between search results?

Comment: You do loose the highlighting, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

"Workaround":

Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit the search,
then use F3 to jump between search results.

You do loose the highlighting of the search-matches,
but can jump from one match to the next with <kbd>F3</kbd>